# NodeMCU ESP8266 DHT22 reading nan (2147483647)

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I am new to electronics and microcontrollers and hope this is the right spot on StackExchange. I have been playing around with an Arduino Micro, connecting different sensors and a display and display data.

I just bought a NodeMCU so I can send sensor values to a database using a DHT22. This is the first test, other sensors will follow.

I am using Arduino Studio with the board configuration for this device.

Everything works fine, Wifi, Serial, but I only get bad readings from the sensor.

- I checked 2 DHT22 with my Arduino, they work.
- I read that the Arduino has integrated pull-ups and a ESP8266 might not have them, so I added 4.7k and 10k between data and 3.3V. But I am not entirely sure about this.
- The DHT22 is using 3.3V on the NodeMCU and the Arduino. Not 5V. -> Arduino works.
- I tried different D pins
- I tried removing or adding code lines like dht.begin, pinMode, etc.
- I used the DHTtest example which also gets bad readings.
- I found other projects - Weather monitoring - which showed their wiring. Some of them also did not use a pull-up resistor. I also tried it without.
- Wiring checked multiple times -> I hope I'm not blind right now.
- Measured the resistors i added -> ok
- Measured the voltage between GND and 3.3V -> ok
- I don't have an oscilloscope (yet) so I don't know whats on the data line.

So I am doing something wrong here but I can't figure out what.

Thanks for help. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Post a schematic and code of what you have tried. Preferably, stick to sample code which someone tested.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/f0x5xada - The example from the DHT library. I changed only the DHTPIN

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IjmFJmf.jpg - Picture is okay? i4 and i5 is 3V and GND. The resistor C6 C7 is 10k, the other one the 4.7k i tried before. e8 is empty. If there is anything else which helps I'd be happy to provide it.

Comment: In this picture data is connected to D3. I modified the example code and set DHTPIN to 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now had some time after a while to look after this problem.

I accidentally found the reason. At first I thought it was a problem with the breadboard or the jumper cables. But later I found out I unplugged the DHT22 while the controller was powered on.

So it is the same problem as [DHT22 needs electrical reset?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/372845/dht22-needs-electrical-reset)